# Refactoring JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, refactoring

hi i want to take out the common content in the 2 FACES JSPS and put in one jsp and include two tabs in that FACESJSP and those two tabs will show the differet content any help with sample code pls?

Comment: Can you provide a summary for the title ? I think that's easier for people to understand at a glance

Comment: Most intelligible refactoring: Select JSP:s, shift+delete, get any other web framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the view technology in question. In JSP you can use `<jsp:include>` for this. In Facelets you can use `<ui:include>` or `<ui:composition>` for this.

When using JSF on JSP, you need to ensure that every include page has its own `<f:subview>` with an **unique** ID.

Basic example:

`main.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<f:view>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Main page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

`header.jsp`

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>

<f:subview id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</f:subview>
```

`footer.jsp`

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>

<f:subview id="footer">
    <h3>Footer</h3>
</f:subview>
```

You can even dynamically include a page, e.g.

```
<jsp:include page="#{bean.page}" />
```

where `#{bean.page}` can return a page relative URL like `pagename.jsp`.

When using JSF on Facelets (you aren't, but this is just informal), the examples for Facelets can be found in their [developer guide](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html). It's far more powerful than JSP and well suited for JSF.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use [tiles](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/11/tilesPaper.html)